# Reshaping numpy (n, )

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with multiple numpy objects that are numpy lists when each list element contains a 2d array. Strangely the shape() function does not reflect this returning only the number of samples overall.

```
x_train.shape, x_test.shape, x_test.iloc[0].shape
#((22507,), (5627,), (25, 100))
```

This code snippet accomplishes the task but I am wondering if there is a better/numpy way to accomplish this.

```
x = []
[x.append(item) for item in x_train]
_np.array(x).shape
# (22507, 25, 100)
```

I have searched through stack overflow and although there are many reshape questions I have not seen one that can solve this problem efficiently.

Comment: Is the dtype `object`?  A 1d array that contains pointers to objects, such as other arrays.  If the arrays all have the same shape, they can be joined into one array with `np.stack`.

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side-effects like that, just use a loop.  List comprehensions should be used to create lists.

Comment: You use the term "numpy list" but that is not a thing.  Perhaps you have a 1D array whose values are 2D arrays.  You should hunt down the source of your data and fix it there, rather than trying to bodge it back into a 3D array afterward.

Comment: @hpaulj The dtype is a pd.Series not object

Comment: @JohnZwinck Alright, I believe that's true that it is a 1D array of 2D arrays at the source I am not sure how to shape it to accept and build into a 3D array.

Comment: You asked about numpy arrays.  The only hint that something in your code is a `pd.Series` is the `x_test.iloc`.  And don't confuse `dtype` with `type`.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah the dtype is float32 good catch

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient way to convert your 1D `dtype=object` array of 2D arrays is:

```
np.stack(x_train)
```

But it would be more efficient to load the original data into a 3D array in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work, the output is the same shape.

Comment: @JacobB: Please  give a specific, complete, runnable example of data in your input format.  I tested the above data which I believe matches what you had in your question, so if you want further help you need to be more specific.